# MacOS Terminal Regex

Tags: regex, macos

I've been able to use this command to open multiple files:

```bash
cd /Volumes/Disk2/blahblah; find ./ -type f -regex '.*SecretPlans_A[1-6]\.docx' | sort | xargs -n 1 open
```

Which opens

DavesSecretPlans_A7
and
BobsSecretPlans_A2

How do I also include "Overview" as well as "A[1-6]"?selection.

I tried something like this (but it doesn't work) thinking that pipe would be used as a sort of 'or' choice:

cd /Volumes/Disk2/blahblah; find ./ -type f -regex '.*SecretPlans_(Overview|A[1-6]).docx' | sort | xargs -n 1 open

I'm still learning, part of the problem is I don't know what terms to search for to find help for this sort of problem.

[Edit] It should be pointed out that whoever marked this as a duplicate didn't comprehend the issue, and none of the questions marked as 'similar' had the solution. This was a MacOS terminal/shell related limitation – I already demonstrated I had an understanding of how to write the regex code, it just wasn't working and I didn'd understand why.

Comment: The answer to this question is not the same as that provided in the one marked as duplicate, that explanation will not work on macOS. The duplicate classification should be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the behavior you require, you would need to use the -E option

-E : Interpret regular expressions following the -regex and -iregex primaries as extended (modern) regular expressions rather than basic regular expressions (BRE's).  The re_format(7) manual page fully describes both formats.

This needs to be the very first parameter provided to the find command.

You would end up with:

```bash
cd /Volumes/Disk2/blahblah; find -E . -type f -regex '.*SecretPlans_(Overview|A[1-6]).docx' | sort | xargs -n 1 open
```

Comment: Thanks, this simple addition to the command line argument completely resolved the issue as it was asked.

Answer (score 0):

If you read `man find` you'll see it says the default regex type is [Emacs regexs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Regexps.html) which are very basic and don't support `|`.

If you run `find -regextype help` it should tell you which other kinds are supported. Maybe try `-regextype posix-extended`.

(I'm on Linux, so the options might be slightly different on Mac.)

Comment: Thanks, these didn't work for me on Mac but thanks so much for you super-fast response!